# Android Espresso listView scroll to

Tags: android, listview, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a list_view, which I want to test.

list_view item layout is `RelativeLayout`, adapter is `ItemAdapter`.

---

This code works fine (item contatining *Daft Punk* is visible):

```
@Test
public void listViewTest() {
    Espresso.onView(withText("Daft Punk")).perform(click());
}
```

Both of this variants fail:

(The scrolling starts, comes to the item and then fails, the error is at the very and of this question.)

```
@Test
public void listViewTest() {
    Espresso.onData(artistWithName("Imagine Dragons")).perform(scrollTo(), click());
}

@Test
public void listViewTest() {
    Espresso.onData(artistWithName("Imagine Dragons")).
        .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list_view))
        .perform(scrollTo(), click());
}
```

---

artistWithName definition:

```
public static Matcher<Object> artistWithName(String expectedName) {
    Checks.checkNotNull(expectedName);
    return artistWithName(equalTo(expectedName));
}

public static Matcher<Object> artistWithName(final Matcher<String> itemMatcher) {
    Checks.checkNotNull(itemMatcher);

    return new BoundedMatcher<Object, ArtistItem>(ArtistItem.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(org.hamcrest.Description description) {
            description.appendText("ArtistTime with name: ");
            itemMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(ArtistItem artistItem) {
            return itemMatcher.matches(artistItem.getName());
        }
    };
}
```

---

Error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll to' on view ' displaying data matching: ArtistTime with name: "Imagine Dragons" within adapter view matching: with id: com.example.iskhakovt.yandextest:id/list_view'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:70)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:53)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at android.support.test.espresso.DataInteraction.perform(DataInteraction.java:130)
at com.example.iskhakovt.yandextest.MainActivityTest.listViewTest(MainActivityTest.java:52)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:240)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1886)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(view has effective visibility=VISIBLE and is descendant of a: (is assignable from class: class android.widget.ScrollView or is assignable from class: class android.widget.HorizontalScrollView))
Target view: "RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=420, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4}"
Further Info: ScrollToAction on a view inside an AdapterView will not work. Use Espresso.onData to load the view.
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onData()` will scroll to the item for you, just remove `scrollTo()` and it should click just fine.

`scrollTo()` is used only for items that are inside the `ScrollView` combined with `onView()`

Comment: What to do if I want to scroll to an item of a list view? (It is not visible yet)

Comment: If the item is in the listview, onData will scroll for you. Even if it is not visible. This is how it works. If it is a ScrollView, then you need to use scrollTo()

Answer (score 0):

To force a ListView to scroll before clicking an item, you can use `swipeUp()` or `swipeDown()` in multiple calls:

```
// scroll the list down a little
onData(anything()).atPosition(0).perform(swipeUp());

// scroll the list down again
onData(anything()).atPosition(2).perform(swipeUp());
```

---

<sup>Note: To quickly add the imports for these methods, put the blinking cursor on the unresolved method, then do Android Studio ➔ <kbd>Help</kbd> ➔ <kbd>Find Action</kbd> ➔ search for `"show context action"` or `"show intention action"` ➔ click on the result option ➔ A popup window will appear ➔ click on `"Import static method ..."`. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to "Show Intention Actions". [More info here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html). Another way is to enable `"Add unambiguous imports on the fly"` in the Settings.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Inside [developer android guide](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/lists) you may find how get item of ListView and perform actions.

```
/**
 * Scrolling and click action inside [ListView]
 */
Espresso.onData(`is`(text))
    .inAdapterView(listView)
    .perform(ViewActions.scrollTo(), ViewActions.click())
```

I thing something like this will work for you:

```
Espresso.onData(`is`("Imagine Dragons"))
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list_view))
    .perform(scrollTo(), click());
```